# Geometry of robust linear model

Tags: regression, robust, geometry

$L_2$ minimisation has a very nice geometric explanation as projection onto a subspace of the appropriate size. Is there a similar "real explanation" for any of the approaches to robust regression?

**Edit:** For example Huber's M estimates of regression and Yohai's MM estimator of regression.

Comment: I think that you ought to define and even outline, the robust regression. For there exist not one type of "robust" regression. Reader would prefer your description/synopsis to reading an external document.

Comment: @ttnphns How about this: is there a geometric description of _any_ of the robust regression models?

Comment: @isomorphismes the problem is that "robust" is a generic term. But based on the documentation for `rlm`, it seems like you're asking about regression with robust standard errors like the Huber-White estimator. If you can clarify, this will be a good question and I'll be interested in the answer.

Comment: @ssdecontrol I'm asking about things along the lines of median polish, not like a trimmed `lm`. BTW please, What other types besides these two am I missing out on?

Comment: @isomorphismes it's not that there are other "types," it's that you can use the word "robust" to mean something like quantile regression, which is robust to outliers.

Comment: @user603 I must have misread the docs then, my mistake. I skimmed them and saw "white estimator"

Comment: @isomorphismes: there are two other robust estimators of regression. All three -MM,LTS,S- are strongly related. For all three, it is advised to have a look at the 'robustbase' package (check for 'ltsReg()' and 'lmrob()' therein). Quantile regression is not robust in the sense that its breakdown point is essentially $0$ (that is why I hesitate to cite it in my answer)

Comment: @user603 But quantile is not really considered robust in the same way that `data %>% winsorise %>% lm` is. Right? I mean quantile regression is estimating _more_ things, not estimating the one thing more safely.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Feel free to write about the geometry of whitened errors too. I've tried to broaden the question to allow as many interesting answers as possible.

Comment: @isomorphismes I was hoping to hear about it myself! And by the way, I didn't mean Winsorizing, I meant the heteroskedasticity-robust variance estimator often attributed to Huber and White. And to think I was asking _other_ people to define their terms...

Comment: @isomorphismes: yes, we perfectly agree: quantile regression is not robust in the sense that it fails to protect against so called bad leverage outliers. That is why I didn't mention it in my answer proper but as a side note to say that there are also higher group of equivariance OLS don't belong to. Note that there *are* high breakdown regression methods that are monotone equivariant.

Comment: @ssdecontrol The winsorisation remark was directed at someone else on a different topic.

Answer (score 4):

Yes! Robust regression has a clear geometric interpretation.

One can think about the geometry of an estimator by looking at the group of equivariance to which it belongs. Quick example;

**Example**  scale estimator $S(x)$ (the usual variance, $\sigma^2(x)$, and the median absolute deviation, $\mbox{mad}(x)$, are two cart bearing members of this group) are  equivariant  to multiplications of the data by a constant:

$$S(\alpha x)=|\alpha|S(x),\quad\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$$

In other words, the group of equivariance defines the transformations of the data which, in some sense, you don't need to care about when using the estimator because when such a transformation is applied to the data, the estimator changes with the data 'in the natural way'.

These groups of equivariance also have bearing on important properties of the estimators such as consistency.

---

Likewise, a regression estimator $T(\pmb x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^p$ is characterized by at least two group of equivariance:

- $T(\pmb x,y)$ is *regression* equivariant: 
  $$T(\pmb x,y+\pmb\beta'x)=T(\pmb x,y)+\pmb\beta,\quad\pmb\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p$$
- $T(\pmb x,y)$ is *affine* equivariant: 
  $$T(\pmb x\pmb A,y)=\pmb A^{-1}T(\pmb x,y)$$
  for any non singular matrix $\pmb A\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$.
  This implies that $T(\pmb x,y)$ is *residual admissible*: the regression estimates only depend on the data through the vector of residuals.

The regression estimator estimated by `rlm`, like the usual OLS estimators, all satisfy affine and regression equivariance.

---

Note that there exist some robust regression estimators that belong to group of equivariance to which OLS doesn't belong (e.g. that have in this sense a stronger geometry than OLS). Think of invariance to monotone transformations that holds for quantile-based estimators such as the $\mbox{mad}(x)$ (and in the case of monotone transformation of the responses for quantile regression) but not for the variance (or the usual OLS estimators).